# Possible bugs in NetTrain? The loss of validation set shouldn't be lower than that of training set

Tags: bugs, neural-networks

I'm very curious why the loss of validation set is even lower than the loss of training set when I use NetTrain.

Say, on this page, https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksSequenceLearning.html#1094728277 ,

for the Q&A RNN trained on the bAbI QA Dataset, the loss of validation set shouldn't be lower than the loss of training set, according to Goodfellow's DL book. Right?

Is it possible that these 2 sets are mistakenly labeled in the NetTrain function when it tries to plot the learning curve? [image]

Comment: Welcome! If you could please add the code to reproduce this, we can try to help.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1935161).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug, this behaviour is explained by the dropout.
The training loss is computed with dropout enabled (as in DropoutLayer[...][..., NetEvaluationMode -> "Train"]).
The validation loss is computed with dropout disabled  (as in DropoutLayer[...][..., NetEvaluationMode -> "Test"]).